# Dag scripts in airflow

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have written Dag scripts in airflow for the functions in my python scripts.For example In dag script I have imported the python script as "from data_extractor import *".I have built a workflow for the functions in the **data_extractor.py** in airflow dag script **data_extractor_dag.py**.But when I make any code changes in the **data_extractor.py** the airflow dag **data_extractor_dag.py** fails to load.During this scenario the airflow UI page is also not loaded.How to use airflow in a better way in this scenario.

Comment: did you install `data_extractor` using pip or did you just place `data_extractor.py` in your dags folder?

Comment: What do you mean by "the airflow dag data_extractor_dag.py fails to load?" Do you mean that you do not see the effect of your changes when the DAG is run?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you have some library code in `data_extractor.py` and your dag definition in `data_extractor_dag.py`. When you edit code in `data_extractor.py`, the changes do not appear in your dag. Is this correct?

With Airflow, both the webserver and the scheduler refresh their view of the dags regularly. When it does this, it looks for python files that contain dags and imports them. This works fine and picks up changes if your code is all contained within the dag definition file. But if you edit an existing library file, or a file imported as an Airflow plugin, then you need to restart the scheduler and webserver in order to pick up on any changes.

Without restarting Airflow, you would expect to see an error if your DAG code is importing something new from a pre-existing library (as the library will not have been updated).